# Minimum no. of tables for the e-r diagram

Tags: database, relational-database, entity-relationship, rdbms

Consider there is a binary relationship R(with no attributes of its own) between two entities A and B in an e-r diagram.
Suppose B to A has a many - one cardinality constraint and B has a total participation in R.

1. How many minimum tables are required to depict this in relational model?
2. Can i merge R and B ? Why or Why not?

Comment: That's a many to many relation there @ghlomali

Comment: Many to one or many to many? Your comment is introducing confusion, @adityakuppa.

Comment: Please show what you have been able to do. We are not here to do your homework. "Merge" isn't a technical term, what are you trying to say?

Comment: many to many OR many to one???? can you give a ER Model instead of explaining?

Comment: If you have many-to-many, I should delete my answer. Then your answer is just 3 Tables and you can not reduce them to 2.

Comment: I deleted my answer, because I thought many-to-one relationship.